How do I proxy web traffic from one PC to another PC listening on burpsuite using NGROK tunnel?
I tried to proxy web traffic from PC A to PC B by setting the proxy settings to the ip address of PC B

and it works completely fine, my burpsuite is listening on port 8081,

the burpsuite certificate has been installed on PC A
and the websites open flawlessly

i can view all the requests

But, as we know this would work only if we are upon the same network, so in order to receive the requests on burpsuite even if PC A and PC B are on a different network, i set up a ngrok tunnel

and set the proxy settings to the ngrok address

But now when i try to visit any site, it shows this error

Please help..

Don't know anything abount NGROK  but surely the address you should be using should be 127.0.0.1 (maybe on port 8080?) and not 6.tcp.ngrok.io?
